# How to create immutable sequelize model properties?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

A simple question:

How to create a immutable [sequelize](/questions/tagged/sequelize) model property?

Whenever I create for example, a Reservation, I would like to have certain properties allowed to be mutable and some of them not.

Comment: why don't you just remove this immutable properties before any update?

Comment: @yBrodsky Can you give an example in the answer section? I don't get what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const _ = require('lodash');

let body = req.body;

/* body:
{
  a: 1,//immutable
  b: 2,//immutable
  c: 3,
  d: 4
}
*/
Model.update(_.omit(body, ['a', 'b']), {
  where: {id: 1}
}).then()....
```

So you will always be updating `c` and `d` because you didn't let anybody update `a` and `b`